# excel how make hyperlink to constant cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have several sections within one sheet. For example rows 100 through 250 could be one section. Rows are often added or removed within each section. So this example section could become 100 through 240 after 10 rows are removed. Also, if rows above this section are added or removed, the beginning of the section would no longer be at row 100.

I'd like to have a hyperlink at the top of the section that takes me to the bottom of the section. And one at the bottom of the section that takes me to the top of the section.

Is there a way to hyperlink to a constant cell? So that when R250 becomes R240 the hyperlink points to the correct location?

[example.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukhvy.gif)

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample?

Comment: @Lee I added a gif image of a sample spreadsheet. I don't see a way to post an excel workbook.